# Making a determination whether DB/Server is down before I kick-off a pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to check whether the database/Server is Online before I kick off a pipeline. In the database is down I want to cancel the pipeline processing. I also would like to log the results in a table.

format (columns) : DBName Status Date

If the DB/Server is down then I want to send an email to concerned team with formatted table showing which DB/Servers are down.

Approach:

Run a query on each of the servers. If there is a result, then format output as shown above. I am using ADF pipeline to achive this. My issue is how do I combine various outputs from different servers.

For e.g.

Server1:

DBName: A  Status: ONLINE runDate:xx/xx/xxxx

Server2:

DBName: B  Status: ONLINE runDate:xx/xx/xxxx

I would like to combine them as follows:

Server DBName  Status runDate

1       A       ONLINE xx/xx/xxxx
2       B       ONLINE xx/xx/xxxx

Use this to update the logging table as well as in the email if I were to send one out.

Is this possible using the Pipeline activities or do I have to use mapping dataflows?

Answer (score 0):

I did similar work a few weeks ago. We make an API where we put all server-related settings or URL endpoint which we need to ping.

You don't require to store username-password (of SQL Server) at all. When you ping the SQL server, it will timeout if it isn't online. If it's online it will give you password related error. This way you can easily figure out whether it's up and running.

AFAIK, If you are using azure-DevOps you can use your service account to log into the SQL server. If you have set up an AD to log into DevOps, this thing can be done in the build script.

Both way you will be able to make sure whether SQL Server is Up and Running or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the actions as tasks in a yaml pipeline

You need something like below:

steps:

- task: Check database status
  register: result
- task: Add results to a file
  shell: "echo text >> filename"
- task: send e-mail
  when: some condition is met

There are several modules to achieve what you need. You need to find the right modules. You can play around with the flow of tasks by registering results and using the when clause.